# Can't create/write to a file in MySQL

Tags: mysql, into-outfile

I've created a stored procedure which create an CSV file from a table.

this is the stored procedure :

```
CREATE DEFINER =  `root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE  `DO_BACKUP` ( IN  `table_name` TEXT )
 NOT DETERMINISTIC CONTAINS SQL SQL SECURITY DEFINER 
BEGIN 
SET @sql = CONCAT(  'SELECT * FROM ', table_name,  ' INTO OUTFILE \'/home/aimad/GestionStock/', DATE_FORMAT( CURDATE( ) ,  '%Y%m%d' ) ,  '_', table_name, '.csv\'' ) ;
    
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql ;
    
    EXECUTE stmt;
    
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

END
```

but when I call this stored procedure, by a table_name in it's parameter, I get this error :

> Can't create/write to file
> '/home/aimad/GestionStock/20130615_BonInterne.csv' (Errcode: 13)

## EDIT :

The OS I'm using is Linux Xubuntu 13.04

Comment: Update question with OS you are using

Answer (score 1):

If you have SELinux enabled, mysql will not write to a directory unless it has the proper context.  First type `getenforce` from a command prompt.  If it returns 'Enforcing', then SELinux is enabled and you have to apply a specific SELinux context to the directory you are trying to read/write to.  This is addtion to having correct permissions.  Navigate to the directory and type `ls -Z` and you will see the SELinux context.  Look at the object_r context.  If it is not mysqld_db_t then your process will not be able to read/write to the directory regardless of permissions.

Make sure that the 'semanage' command is installed so you can set the context.  To see what an SELinux file context looks like for mysql, type the following at the command prompt as root:

`semanage fcontext -l | grep mysql`

You will see quite a few lines but look specifically at /var/lib/mysql, which mysql can write to.  The fcontext for this directory is mysqld_db_t.  This is what you need to apply to the directory that you want your process to read and write from.  You do this as follows:

`semanage fcontext -a -t mysqld_db_t '/somedir(/.*)?'`

Don't forget the single quotes around the directory.  Next you want to make sure that the fcontext is applied recursively to this directory.  Type the following:

`restorecon -RFvv /somedir`

This ensures that all existing files and sub-directories have the proper fcontext.  Mysql can read and write assuming that permissions are correct.  The first time I did this, I tripped up because I had my directory setup to allow anyone to read, but not write.  So I was able to use the mysql 'infile' command, but not 'outfile'.  Make sure that user mysql can write to the directory.

If you don't care about SELinux you can turn it off and avoid everything I outlined above.  I like the additional layer of security, so I work with it.

Answer (score 0):

As stated [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cannot-create.html), you have either permission or space-related problem.

Comment: Yes, I saw this article when I googled about the problem, but I couldn't know what I must to do, in the article I've to add this `line [mysqld]
tmpdir=C:/temp` into my option file which I don't know where to find it

Comment: Come again? What in particular you can't find?

Comment: that file where I"ve to add the line `[mysqld] tmpdir=`

Comment: Then it is definitely permissions issue. Leave `tmpdir` alone - it's Windows-related problem. Just check, what user is your mysql server is using, and then check if this user has write permissions on `/home/aimad/GestionStock/`. I guess, it's not, cause it looks like your home dir.

Comment: Well, did you check mysql user's permissions on it?